# No route found after cache saving with Symfony2 in production

Tags: php, symfony

I added a simple page with a new route in my Symfony website in production. Before it was working well but since then all my pages are sending to a 404 errors after a while except for my homepage... When I delet the cache it works well but few time after it begins to have the errors again on the pages...

I don't know what is the problem, here are the files of the new page I added:

```
{#info.html.twig author: Nicolas Le Roux #}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-ico" href="web/favicon.ico" />
    <title>BibliShare - Les 8 étapes indispensables pour faire une bonne recherche bibliographique.</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Le guide essentiel pour effectuer des recherches bibliographiques efficaces en 8 étapes." />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/global.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/info.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
    <header class="row"> 
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="bs">
                    <a href="{{ path('biblishare_index') }}" title="BibliShare"><img src="{{ asset('css/img/biblishare.png') }}" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </header>
            <div class="col-lg-12 middle text-center">
                <p>
                   <map name="map_info" id="id_map">
                      <area shape="rect" coords="200,1359,400,1375" href="http://www.sciencespo.fr/bibliotheque/fr" alt="Bibliothèque de Sciences Po" target="_blank" />
                      <area shape="rect" coords="203,1391,313,1410" href="http://www.scholar.google.com/" alt="Google Scholar" target="_blank" />
                      <area shape="rect" coords="204,1426,248,1443" href="http://www.cairn.info/" alt="Cairn" target="_blank" />
                      <area shape="rect" coords="203,1444,247,1463" href="http://www.jstor.org/" alt="Jstor" target="_blank" />
                      <area shape="rect" coords="205,1478,256,1494" href="http://www.persee.fr/" alt="Persée" target="_blank" />
                      <area shape="rect" coords="202,1542,423,1561" href="http://www.biblishare.com/" alt="BibliShare" title="BibliShare" target="_blank" />
                      <area shape="rect" coords="319,3055,556,3072" href="http://grebib.bnf.fr/html/presenter_bibliographie.html" alt="Normes de présentations" target="_blank" />
                      <area shape="rect" coords="203,3091,254,3108" href="https://www.zotero.org/" alt="Zotero" target="_blank" />
                      <area shape="rect" coords="274,3094,342,3108" href="http://www.mendeley.com/" alt="Mendeley" target="_blank" />
                      <area shape="rect" coords="545,3091,610,3108" href="http://www.worldcat.org/?lang=fr" alt="WorldCat" target="_blank" />
                   </map>

                </p>
                <img src="{{ asset('css/img/infographie.png') }}" alt="le guide pour vos recherches bibliographiques" usemap="#map_info" width="800" height="3198"/>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 middle text-center">
                <div class="twitter-share-button2"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.biblishare.com/info" data-via="BibliShare" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a></div>
                <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.biblishare.com/info" data-layout="button"></div>
            </div>
    <footer>
        <a href="{{ path('biblishare_index') }}" alt="Faire une recherche sur BibliShare">www.biblishare.com</a>
    </footer>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
        <script>
          (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

          ga('create', 'UA-54997972-4', 'auto');
          ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the routing file:

```
biblishare_index:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: BiblishareBundle:Default:index }

biblishare_select:
    path:     /select/
    defaults: { _controller: BiblishareBundle:Default:select }

biblishare_validation:
    path:     /validation
    defaults: { _controller: BiblishareBundle:Default:validation }

biblishare_add:
    path:    /add
    defaults: { _controller: BiblishareBundle:Default:member }

biblishare_profile:
    path:    /profile
    defaults: { _controller: BiblishareBundle:Profile:show }

biblishare_biblio:
    path:    /profile/{queryId}
    defaults: { _controller: BiblishareBundle:Profile:biblio }

biblishare_best:
    path:    /best
    defaults: { _controller: BiblishareBundle:Default:best }

biblishare_info:
    path:    /info
    defaults: { _controller: BiblishareBundle:Default:info }

target_route:
    path:     /select
    defaults: { _controller: BiblishareBundle:Default:select }
```

Thank you for your help, I'm in a OVH server.

Comment: Edit your app.php file: $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);  That will turn on debugging and maybe show some better error messages.  If that does not help then run in development mode.  Servers can do strange things.

Comment: I sugest to read through the app/logs/dev.log, and app/logs/prod.log, this can lead you to the source of the problem.

Comment: the log says : "request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /info/"" at /home/biblishazj/www/biblishare/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 2420 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /info/\" at /home/biblishazj/www/biblishare/app/cache/prod/classes.php:2420, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /home/biblishazj/www/biblishare/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:261)"} []"

Comment: From Symfony's perspective, /info is not the same as /info/.  Where is the trailing slash coming from?  Bit of a mystery but perhaps your json code is adding it? Maybe use firebug to see what is actually being sent to the server.  This might be useful: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html but it would be better to trace down the trailing slash or adjust your routes accordingly.

Comment: Actually it happens when I put biblishare/info and it is the same for all my route /login etc... I just need to remove the cache and it works for a while...